# How to access BuildContext in main() method of Flutter launcher class?

Tags: flutter, widget, program-entry-point

I need to access **`BuildContext`** in **`main() {}`** method of the `main.dart` class to show a `popUp` dialog in firebase `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` method when a new push notification is received, how to access it while there is no **`BuildContext`** in **`main()`** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really.

In your `main` function in your `main.dart`, you have to call `runApp()` to launch your first widget, and within this widget, you will have access to `BuildContext` since all the stateful/stateless widget will receive the BuildContext through their `build` method.

For example you may want to do something like this:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
      MySuperApplication(),
  );
}



class MySuperApplicationextends StatefulWidget {
  const MySuperApplication({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MySuperApplicationState createState() => _MySuperApplicationState();
}

class _MySuperApplicationState extends State<MySuperApplication> {
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // You have access to your BuildContext here, and you can initialize FirebaseMessaging.
    _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("all");
    
    // return any widget.
    return WhatEverWidget()
  }
}
```